# How to send a embedded image in a email using a compute engine instance Google Cloud

Tags: python-3.x, image, smtp, google-compute-engine

I am trying to send a image in a embedded email using Python and SMTP library. It works fine in my Jupyter Lab notebook. However I need to run this same code in a Google Cloud Compute Engine instance.

This is the line of code the produces the error:

```
smtp_obj.sendmail(msg['From'], msg["To"].split(","), msg.as_string
```

And the error is

[image]

I am not sure why this is causing a issue in Compute Engine, I am currently using a debian instance.

Comment: It seems that you do not have a string attribute, and as a result, `msg.as_string` doesn't return anything, so you're calling the `strip()` method on something that doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes, i noticed that error, it runs fine in the notebook which leads me to believe that the issue is with the VM not being able to embed a image.

Comment: It's a bit weird that it runs on your Jupyter notebook as there're inconsistencies within the python code itself. In any case I guess that you need to add additional details as the OS of your VM, and the package you are using to deploy your code, to gain more visibility on this post.